# Find the maximal domain for a function and its derivative, and an explicit form for the derivative

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, derivatives

$$ f(x)= \sum_{n=1}^\infty{\frac{(-1)^{n-1}x^{3n+1}}{3n+1}} $$
As mentioned in the title I have to find where the function is defined, where its derivative exists and its derivative... It looks like a logarithm, but I'm not sure how to get to that ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The radius of convergence of the given power series is clearly $1$, and for any $z\in(-1,1)$

$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1} z^{3n+1}}{3n+1} = \sum_{n\geq 1}\int_{0}^{z}(-1)^{n+1}t^{3n}\,dt = \int_{0}^{z}\left(1-\frac{1}{1+t^3}\right)\,dt$$
where the exchange of $\sum$ and $\int$ is allowed by absolute convergence. The problem boils down to finding a primitive for $\frac{1}{1+t^3}$, and by partial fraction decomposition
$$ \frac{1}{1+t^3} = \frac{1}{3(1+t)}+\frac{2-t}{3(1-t+t^2)}$$
hence:
$$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1} z^{3n+1}}{3n+1} = {\small z-\frac{1}{3}\log(z+1)-\frac{\pi\sqrt{3}}{18}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\arctan\left(\frac{2z-1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)+\frac{1}{6}\log(1-z+z^2)} $$
holds for any $z\in(-1,1)$. By partial summation, you may prove it holds for $z=1$ too.

---

An equivalent approach is to apply a [discrete Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform) to the power series of $\log(1+z)$, by exploiting $\log(1+z)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}z^n}{n}$ and the fact that for any integer $n$, by setting $\omega=\exp\frac{2\pi i}{3}$, we get that $\frac{1}{3}\left(1+\omega^n+\omega^{2n}\right)$ equals $1$ if $n\in 3\mathbb{Z}$ and zero otherwise.

---

Of course, over the range of convergence $z\in(-1,1)$ we simply have $f'(x)=\frac{x^3}{x^3+1}$, since we may apply a termwise differentiation to the given power series.